# Need to add session_start() in every method in controller

Tags: php

I use simple mvc in my project. This is my base **Controller**

```
<?php
class Controller {
    function __construct() {
        $this->view = new View();           
    }

    public function loadModel($name, $modelPath = 'models/') {
        $path = $modelPath . $name .'_model.php';

        if(file_exists($path)) {
            require $modelPath . $name .'_model.php';

            $modelName = $name . '_Model';
            $this->model = new $modelName();
        }
    }
}
```

this is base **View** class

```
<?php

class View {
    function __construct(){         
    }

    public function render($name) {
        require 'views/layouts/header.php';
        require 'views/' . $name . '.php';
        require 'views/layouts/footer.php';     
    }
}
```

I added `session_start();` on the top **header.php**

```
<?php session_start(); ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
....
```

and this is how I display error from controller in the view

```
<?php 
  if (isset($_SESSION['errors']) && count($_SESSION['errors']) > 0) {

    echo '<div class="row"><div class="col-lg-10 col-lg-push-2">';
    echo '<div class="alert alert-dismissible alert-danger"><button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">×</button><strong>Error!</strong><ul class="errors-list">';
    foreach ($_SESSION['errors'] as $error) {      
      echo '<li>' . $error['message'] . '</li>';
    }
    echo '</ul></div></div></div>';
}
?>
```

but anyway I need to add `session_start();` in the methods in controller, otherwise $_SESSION['errors'] isn't set

```
<?php
class User extends Controller {
    function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();          
    }

public function create() {
            $name = $_POST['name'];

            session_start();
            unset($_SESSION['errors']);
            unset($_SESSION['variables']);

            $_SESSION['errors'] = array();
            $_SESSION['variables'] = array();

            $count = $this->model->checkIfUserExists($name);
            if($count > 0) {       
                $_SESSION['errors'][] = array(
                    'message'   => 'User Already exists',
                );  

                $_SESSION['variables']  = array(
                    'name'     => $_POST['name'],
                    'password' => $_POST['password'],
                );  

                header('location: ' . URL . 'user/registration');
                exit;
            } 

            if(empty($_POST['name']) || empty($_POST['password'])) {
                $_SESSION['errors'][] = array(
                    'message'   => 'Fill required fields',
                );

                $_SESSION['variables']  = array(
                    'name'     => $_POST['name'],
                    'password' => $_POST['password'],
                );

                header('location: ' . URL . 'user/registration');
                exit;
            }       

            $data = array();
            $data['name'] = $_POST['name'];
            $data['password'] = $_POST['password'];
            $data['role'] = 2;

            $userId = $this->model->create($data);
            if($userId) {

                $_SESSION['errors'] = $data['role'];
                $_SESSION['loggedIn'] = true;
                $_SESSION['userid'] = $userId;

                header('location: ' . URL);
                exit;
            } 

            $_SESSION['errors'][] = array(
                'message'   => 'Error. Try again',
            );

            $_SESSION['variables']  = array(
                'name'     => $_POST['name'],
                'password' => $_POST['password'],
            );

            header('location: ' . URL . 'user/registration');
            exit;
            }                   
        }
```

and I don't understand why I need to add `session_start();` in every method to make session works?

**UPD**
When I add check to method in controller

```
        public function create() {
        $name = $_POST['name'];
        if(isset($_SESSION)) {
            echo "yes";
        } else {
            echo "no";  
        }

        die();
```

it displays 'no'

But when I tried to add `session_start();` in construct

```
class User extends Controller {
        function __construct(){
            parent::__construct();
            session_start();            
        }
```

I got an error

```
Notice: A session had already been started - ignoring session_start() in C:\xampp\htdocs\test\views\layouts\header.php on line 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Session needs to be initiated on every page call if you want to use it. This is a facility so you can have pages render faster if session is not needed and there is no overhead.

If you do not want to use session explicitly you can call that in your parent controller or bootstrap file which calls the class files.

On the other hand you can explicitly keep session on from your php.ini settings.

Comment: When I add check to method in controller

      `public function create() {
   $name = $_POST['name'];
   if(isset($_SESSION)) {
       echo "yes";
   } else {
    echo "no"; 
   }

   die();`

it displays 'no'

But when I tried to add `session_start();` in construct 
 

    `class User extends Controller {
      function __construct(){
       parent::__construct();
       session_start();   
      }`

I got an error 

    `Notice: A session had already been started - ignoring session_start() in C:\xampp\htdocs\test\views\layouts\header.php on line 1`

Comment: It simply means that if you have session_start() function call anywhere else you should remove that as your parent controller already has a session start.